# Sacar palabra de array de char que empieze y acabe por 'a' en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo la siguiente cadena

```
String cadena="la amiga es mia";
```

lo paso a un array de chars:

```
char[]caracteres=cadena.toCharArray
```

ahora lo que quiero hacer es de ese array sacar las palabras que empiezen y acaben por 'a' en este caso tiene que salir

```
palabras que empiezan y acaban por 'a':amiga
```

¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: No podrías, separar la cadena a través de un split, de este modo tendrias palabra a palabra, y luego con su longitud, una condición de si la de la posicion 0, o la de la ultima posición son 'a', que salgan?

Comment: Yo te recomendaría no pasarla a un array de chars. `String` tiene un par de metodos que te pueden ayudar como `.split(" ")` que en tu caso te retornaria un array con las palabras

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Las opciones que te comentan son las más sencillas. Intentalo y si tienes problemas o errores concretos, edita la pregunta para mejorarla segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Asumiendo que la sentencia no termina con un punto (`.`), entonces hacer `.split(" ")` está bien, luego de eso sólo itera cada elemento en el array de `String` para comprobar la primera y la última letra.

Comment: En el caso de que la respuesta de [sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16349/sioesi) haya solucionado tu problema, es recomendable que lo marques como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo utilizar `split` para así separar la palabra. y luego verificar si el primer y ultimo carácter son a.

Asegurate de tener las letras en minúsculas o mayúsculas (yo escogí minúsculas), luego cree una `ArrayList` para guardar todas las palabras que empiezan y terminan con `a`

Ademas agregue que si la palabra viene con acentos, de igual manera las busque. Buscara coincidencias con Amiga (sin acento) pero mostrara el resultado con Amigá

```
String string = "la Amigá es mía azula";
String palabraLimpia = new String(string);
palabraLimpia = Normalizer.normalize(palabraLimpia, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
palabraLimpia = palabraLimpia.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println(palabraLimpia);
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
String[] parts2 = palabraLimpia.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < parts2.length; i++) {
    char[]caracteres = parts2[i].toCharArray();
    int largo = caracteres.length;
    if (Character.toUpperCase(caracteres[0]) == 'A' && Character.toUpperCase(caracteres[largo-1]) == 'A') {
        lista.add(parts[i]);
    }
}
for (String palabra: lista) {
    System.out.println(palabra);
}
```

Comment: Si esta comparación: 
if (caracteres[0] == 'a' && caracteres[largo-1] == 'a') ... la haces así:
if (Character.toUpperCase(caracteres[0]) == 'A' && Character.toUpperCase(caracteres[largo-1]) == 'A') da igual si empieza por minúscula o mayúscula y al acabar lo mismo

Comment: como? @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: con el Character.toUpperCase(caracteres[0]) lo que haces es pasar a mayuscula el primer caracter, así que con eso, comparando con 'A' ya está (no se como explicarlo mejor, perdona)

Comment: en una linea anterior `string = string.toLowerCase();` dejo todos los caracteres en minuscula, no es necesario hacer esa validacion despues!

Comment: ahora si, antes no lo pasabas, símplemente llamabas a la función pero no le asignabas el valor. Eso si, modificas la frase y no se si es correcto del todo. A la hora de imprimir te va a sacar las palabras en minúscula y el usuario las ha podido meter en mayúsculas

Comment: toda la razon, gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano por el alcance!

Comment: de nada =), eso si, ahora sobra la línea string = string.toLowerCase();

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano actualice mi respuesta aceptando ademas acentos, que te parece?

Answer (score 3):

Primero pasamos la cadena a un array.
Después recorremos el array y comprobamos la primera y ultima letra de cada palabra.
Si ambas son "a" la eliminamos y la añadimos al ArrayList de palabras eliminadas.
Luego pintamos la frase original sin las palabras eliminadas y debajo las palabras que acabamos de eliminar

```
String texto = "La cadena es amiga mia";
String [] array = texto.split(" ");
ArrayList eliminadas = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].charAt(0) == 'a' && array[i].charAt(array[i].length()-1) == 'a'){
            eliminadas.add(array[i]);
            array[i] = "";
        }

    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(array).replace(",","") + "\n Palabras eliminadas : ");
    for(int j = 0; j<eliminadas.size(); j++){
        System.out.print(eliminadas.get(j) + ", ");
    }
```

Si te fijas, cuando pinte la frase de las palabras eliminadas, donde estaba la palabra "amiga" ahora hay dos espacios, la solución a eso lo buscas tu :P